# How to hide or show a div depending on the state of an input

Tags: javascript

How to show or hide a div depending on the type of radio selected

For the moment I have a code when I click on 2 cars it displays j'ai sélectionne 2"

On the other hand if I click on the 3 other radio buttons I have "j'ai sélectionne 3" which are displayed for each button

I wish that if I select the first radio button it displays j'ai sélectionne 2

if I select the second radio button it displays j'ai sélectionne 3

if I select the third button it displays j'ai sélectionne 3

if I select the fourth button it displays j'ai sélectionne 3

Thanks for the help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.desc").hide();
  $("input[name$='choix_livraison']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).data("target");;
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#" + test).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

2 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="1" value="1"><br>

3 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="2" value="2"> <br> 

3 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="2" value="3"> <br>

3 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="2" value="4"> <br>
<br>

<div id="1" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionne 2
</div>
<div id="2" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionne 3
</div>
```

Comment: The description of the desired output matches the output produced. What am I missing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code in the question already does precisely what the OP wants it to do, and OP has chosen not to respond to comments asking what the problem is; which leaves the question itself somewhat without purpose (until clarification is made).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-used the code you provided, fixing the numbers from 1 to 4.

EDIT: made it vanilla JS

```js
function hide_all() {

  document.querySelectorAll("div.desc").forEach(elem => elem.style.display = 'none');
}
hide_all();

document.querySelectorAll("input[name$='choix_livraison']").forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var test = elem.getAttribute("data-target");
    hide_all()
    document.querySelector("#a" + test).style.display = 'block';
  })
});
```

```html
<label>1 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="1" value="1"></label><br>
<label>2 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="2" value="2"></label><br>
<label>3 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="3" value="3"></label><br>
<label>4 Cars <input type="radio" name="choix_livraison" data-target="4" value="4"></label><br>
<br>

<div id="a1" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionne 1
</div>
<div id="a2" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionne 2
</div>
<div id="a3" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionne 3
</div>
<div id="a4" class="desc">
  j'ai sélectionne 4
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is incompatible with https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js..is it possible to do it in pure javascript